# How to initialize Pixate Freestyle with Swift

Tags: swift, pixate

How do I initialize Pixate Freestyle on iOS using Swift?

The documentation say to do

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [PixateFreestyle initializePixateFreestyle];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

How do I do that with Swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AppDelegate.swift, comment out or remove:

```
//@UIApplicationMain
```

Create a main.swift that contains:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// Override point for customization after application launch.
PixateFreestyle.initializePixateFreestyle()
UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

For XCode 6.3 and higher replace the `UIApplicationMain` line with:

```
UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

And for Cocoapod-based installs (at least) remember to create (and configure in the target Build Settings) a bridging header with the correct import line:

```
#import <PixateFreestyle/PixateFreestyle.h>
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for figuring this out. I had been wondering.

Comment: I was hoping that the Pixate people would respond.  I do know that they monitor the keyword Pixate...

Comment: The last line should be `UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))` with Xcode 6.3